# scala combinator parser not backtracking as I would have thought…

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I've been staring myself blind on this problem I have and I guess this will probably be a real stupid question. But I have to swallow my pride.

I have this combinator parser that doesn't backtrack like I thought it would. I've been reducing it down to a small example without entirely removing context. Feels like "foobar"-examples are just harder to read. Here I go:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ParserBacktrackTest extends RegexParsers with Spec with ShouldMatchers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false

  lazy val optSpace = opt(whiteSpace)
  lazy val number = """\d+([\.]\d+)?""".r
  lazy val numWithOptSpace = number <~ optSpace

  private def litre = numWithOptSpace <~ ("litre" | "l")
  def volume = litre ^^ { case _ => "volume" }

  private def namedPieces = numWithOptSpace <~ ("pcs") ^^ { case _ => "explPcs" }
  private def implicitPieces = number ^^ { case _ => "implPcs" }
  protected def unitAmount = namedPieces | implicitPieces

  def nameOfIngredient = ".*".r

  def amount = volume | unitAmount
//  def amount = unitAmount
  protected def ingredient = (amount <~ whiteSpace) ~ nameOfIngredient

  describe("IngredientParser") {
    it("should parse volume") {
      shouldParse("1 litre lime")
    }
    it("should parse explicit pieces") {
      shouldParse("1 pcs lime")
    }
    it("should parse implicit pieces") {
      shouldParse("1 lime")
    }
  }

  def shouldParse(row: String) = {
    val result = parseAll(ingredient, row)
    result match {
      case Success(value, _) => println(value)
      case x => println(x)
    }
    result.successful should be(true)
  }
}
```

So what happens is that the third test fails:

```
(volume~lime)
(explPcs~lime)
[1.4] failure: string matching regex `\s+' expected but `i' found

1 lime
   ^
```

So it seems the `litre-parser` consumed the l and then it failed when it couldn't find any space. But I would have thought that it would backtrack then and try the next production rule. Obviously the `implicitPieces` parser parses this line because if I remove the preceding volume parser (remove the comment), it succeeds

```
(implPcs~litre lime)
(explPcs~lime)
(implPcs~lime)
```

Why isn't `amount` backtracking? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't backtrack because for `1 lime`

- `ingredient` starts out with `amount`
- `amount` starts with `volume`
- `volume` starts with `litre`, and
- `litre` successfully consumes `1 l` of `1 lime`

So `litre`, `volume` and `amount` were all successful! This is why then the whole thing continues with the second part of `ingredient`, namely `whiteSpace`.

HTH!

Comment: I just don't get that? I mean it has to be able to backtrack when it fails. A non-backtracking CFG parser wouldn't be worth much. I mean this works:

`{def foo = "foo";  
  def bar = "bar"; 
  def baz = "baz"; 

  def foobarbaz = foo ~ bar ~ baz;  
  def foobarfoo = foo ~ bar ~ foo; 

  def p = foobarbaz | foobarfoo;  

  describe("foobar-parser") {  
    it("should parse it") {  
      shouldParseWith(p, "foobarfoo")  
    }  
  }}`

Comment: @hedefalk In this example `foobarbaz` fails, so `|` tries the alternative. In your question, `volume` succeeds, so `|` doesn't try the alternative.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to show. @hedefalk: It may be that it's just a matter of priority so that you would only need to rework a minor part of your grammar. As Daniel said, in `a | b` the right-hand side will only be evaluated once the left-hand side fails which is not the case in your OP. See if you can rearrange one or more rules to get the priorities that you want to have.

Comment: I realize I didn't understand how these parsers work at all. Changing: `def amount = (volume | unitAmount) <~ whiteSpace` to `def amount = (volume <~ whiteSpace) | (unitAmount <~ whiteSpace)` makes the backtracking work. So it only backtracks over a disjunction (`|`) but sequencing with `~` is gready?

Comment: But what are then `~!` for? I still don't get it. I'm probably real slow today :´(

Comment: Ah, NOW I get it. "the right-hand side will only be evaluated once the left-hand side fails". So it's the disjunction that makes it greedy. If I have `(p | q)` and `p` succeeds, `q` will never be tried in a backtracking of a composition…?

Comment: Yep, there's no need to try `q` in that case and that's why it didn't backtrack.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to post a minimal example illustrating my misunderstanding. I thought this would succeed:

```
  def foo = "foo" | "fo"
  def obar = "obar"

  def foobar = foo ~ obar

  describe("foobar-parser") {
    it("should parse it") {
      shouldParseWith(foobar, "foobar")
    }
  }
```

but backtracking over `|` doesn't work that way. The disjunctive parser will consume "foo" and never give it back.

It has to be normalized so the disjunction is moved to the top level:

```
def workingFooBar = ("foo" ~ obar) | ("fo" ~ obar)
```

Comment: Is there any parser library in scala where the transformation is done automatically?